# Should I write "Notes from the Microsoft immersion session" or "Notes from Microsoft immersion session"?

Tags: articles, proper-nouns

Should I write "Notes from the Microsoft immersion session" or "Notes from Microsoft immersion session"? In general we always say,"Notes from the immersion session". Does having Microsoft (with capital M) in front of immersion session (common noun) make it a proper noun?

Comment: Consider "This is Ford factory" and "This is the Ford factory". Which one sounds right? It is the head noun ('factory'; '[immersion] session' in your case) that informs article use.

Comment: Thanks Edwin, this is very helpful. 

So in this case, since the head noun is session (common noun), I should use "the"?

Comment: I think the head noun might be 'immersion session' (an open compound noun, rather than a strrong collocation) here, but either way, the head noun is a common noun. So 'the' is needed. You chose a tricky example. And note that capitalised nouns sometimes _do_ take 'the': 'NASA is still developing the module that will provide living quarters for the astronauts aboard the International Space Station' ([The Writing Center](https://writing.wisc.edu/handbook/style/ccs_nounstrings/)].